# ASIHTTP Request is not working and application is crashing when i tried to release the Object of my Class

Tags: ios, ios4

In my Main class i am creating an object of my `AlbumFetcher` class and calling some functions and relasing the object .

```
AlbumFetcher *_albumFetcher = [[AlbumFetcher alloc] init];
[_albumFetcher getData];
[_albumFetcher release];
```

When i relaesed the object after calling some functions , ASIHTTP request finish method is not calling and application is crashing . But when i am not releasing the object everything is working perfect . What i have to do

```
AlbumFetcher *_albumFetcher = [[AlbumFetcher alloc] init];
[_albumFetcher getData];
//[_albumFetcher release]; // now ASIHTTP Request n everything is working fine .....
```

In AlbumFetcher Class i have this functions ...

```
-(void)getData{

    _fullsizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/site/alb_iphone"];        

    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:_fullsizeURL];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(albumrequestDone:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(albumrequestFailed:)];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
- (void)albumrequestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    // here my code
}
- (void)albumrequestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
    // here my code    
}
```

So where i am going wrong and where i have to release the object .

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `ASIHTTPRequest` works asynchronously, i.e. in another thread. So your request is not done after `[_albumFetcher getData]` finishes.

Your request is not finished until `albumrequestDone:request` or `albumrequestFailed:request` finished. My suggestion is put `[self release]` at the end of those two functions.

Comment: or use AlbumFetcher *_albumFetcher = [[[AlbumFetcher alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: or have your `AlbumFetcher dealloc` method cancel & cleanup the `ASIHTTPRequest`